# pyqt4 button click handler

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a problem usin pyqt4:
here is the code I'm using, the point is that if in the event handler for the pushOk button clicked I call chiedi_numeri() it does not show me any form, while if I call chiedi_numeri() it says that argument 3 og QObjectConnect has an invalid type. how can I solve it?
thanks

```
class Ui_dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog):
        dialog.setObjectName("dialog")
        dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushOk = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog)
        self.pushOk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushOk.setObjectName("pushOk")
        self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(dialog)
        self.radioButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 261, 18))
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(dialog)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 281, 18))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.radioButton_3 = QtGui.QRadioButton(dialog)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 100, 281, 18))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.labelRisultato = QtGui.QLabel(dialog)
        self.labelRisultato.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 200, 261, 51))
        self.labelRisultato.setObjectName("labelRisultato")

        self.retranslateUi(dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog)


    def retranslateUi(self, dialog):
        dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Fibonacci", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushOk.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Ok", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.radioButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Calcola la serie di Fibonacci", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Calcola la serie di Fibonacci in un intervallo", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Calcola l\'ennesimo elemento della serie di Fibonacci", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

def fibonacci():  
    a , b = 0, 1  
    while 1:  
        a, b = b, a + b  
        yield a

def chiedi_numeri(): 
    try:
            max_ = int(raw_input("Inserisci un numero: "))
            if max_ <= 0 :
                print "Il numero", max_, "non e' positivo!"
            else:
                start = 0  
                for i in fibonacci():  
                        if start > max_:
                            break
                        else:
                            start += 1
                            if start == max_:
                                    print  "Il", max_, "numero della sequenza di Fibonacci e'", i
    except ValueError:
            print "Non hai inserito un numero!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_dialog()
    ui.setupUi(dialog)
    app.connect(ui.pushOk, Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"), chiedi_numeri())
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

When you connect a Signal to a python function, you pass the function object.  In other words, you omit the trailing parentheses since you are passing the function not calling it.  Try changing that line to read `app.connect(ui.pushOk, Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"), chiedi_numeri)`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you're doing wrong is in this line:

```
    app.connect(ui.pushOk, Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"), chiedi_numeri())
```

You want this function to run when the button is clicked, not when the connection is made.  To do that, remove the parentheses after `chiedi_numeri`:

```
    app.connect(ui.pushOk, Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"), chiedi_numeri)
```

That should then wire up your button correctly.

However, I'm not sure what you mean by the following:

> I call chiedi_numeri() it does not show me any form

What do you mean by 'form'?  Are you expecting another window to pop up and ask for a number?  At the moment, your program asks for a number in the terminal/shell/console window you started the application from.

Answer (score 0):

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui 
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog):
        dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dialog"))
        dialog.resize(600, 400)
        self.pushOk = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog)
        self.pushOk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushOk.setObjectName("pushOk")

```
    self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(dialog)
    self.radioButton.setEnabled(True)
    self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 261, 18))
    self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
    self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
    self.radioButton_2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(dialog)
    self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 70, 281, 18))
    self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
    self.radioButton_3 = QtGui.QRadioButton(dialog)
    self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 100, 281, 18))
    self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
    self.labelRisultato = QtGui.QLabel(dialog)
    self.labelRisultato.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 200, 261, 51))
    self.labelRisultato.setObjectName("labelRisultato")

    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(dialog)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 39, 150, 18))
    self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 248);"))
    self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))

    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(dialog)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 220, 250, 150))
    self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);font: 17pt \"Adobe Courier\";"))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))



    self.retranslateUi(dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog)


def retranslateUi(self, dialog):
    dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Fibonacci", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushOk.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Ok", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.radioButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Calcola la serie di Fibonacci", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.radioButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Calcola la serie di Fibonacci in un intervallo", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.radioButton_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog", "Calcola l\'ennesimo elemento della serie di Fibonacci", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

class StaxQT4(QtGui.QDialog): 
 def **init**(self):

```
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.connect(self.ui.pushOk, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.chiedi_numeri)
```

def fibonacci(self):
    a , b = 0, 1
    while 1:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a

def chiedi_numeri(self): 
    try:
            max_ = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
            if max_ <= 0 :
                self.ui.lineEdit.setText( "Il numero %s non e' positivo!" % str(max_) )
            else:
                start = 0
                for i in self.fibonacci():
                        if start > max_:
                            break
                        else:
                            start += 1
                            if start == max_:
                        self.ui.textEdit.setText("Il %s numero della sequenza di Fibonacci e'" % str(max_))
                                    self.ui.textEdit.append(str(i))
    except ValueError:
            self.ui.lineEdit.settext("Non hai inserito un numero!")

if **name** == "**main**":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

```
myapp = StaxQT4()
myapp.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hmm, this copy paste does not really work, basically you want to separate the interface setup class Ui_Dialog and the application class
StaxQT4 ,also the other comments given are correct
See this line:
 self.connect(self.ui.pushOk, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.chiedi_numeri)