# Python PyQt - How to edit a variable in another function when function is run multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

In my PyQt5 program, I have tabs and use one function for creating the same tab multiple times. In PyQt, to run code when a button is clicked you need to connect it to another function. In the createATab function, I have a QLineEdit which needs to be edited when a button is clicked. Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
class Example(QWidget, QWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
    def runThisWhenButtonClicked(self):
        getText = editThisLine.text()
        editThisLine.clear() # edits variable in other function except other function is run multiple times
    def addTheTab(self, username):
        addingTab = QWidget()
        aButton = QPushButton("Stuff")
        editThisLine = QLineEdit()
        aButton.clicked.connect(self.runThisWhenButtonClicked)
        tabGrid = QGridLayout(addingTab)
        tabGrid.addWidget(editThisLine, 3, 1, 4, 2)
        tabGrid.addWidget(aButton, 3, 3, 4, 3)
        tab_widget.addTab(addingTab, str(username))    

    def initUI(self):
        global tab_widget
        tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        listwidget = QListWidget()
        listwidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.addTheTab)
        splitterrr = QSplitter()
        splitterrr.addWidget(listwidget)
        splitterrr.addWidget(tab_widget)
        QListWidgetItem("Test1", listwidget)
        QListWidgetItem("Test2", listwidget)
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(splitterrr)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

I have read through this and although it does explain a lot, it doesn't explain how to solve this issue.

[pyqt4 button click handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160815/pyqt4-button-click-handler)

This explains how you are only passing the function, not calling it. So, passing variables to the runThisWhenButtonClicked function is not possible.

Comment: Short version: use `self.editThisLine`. Longer version: [read up on classes, instances, and instance properties](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/).

Comment: About the short version - returned an error: "'Example' object has no attribute 'editThisLine'. About the longer version - thanks for the link!

Comment: You have to use `self.editThisLine` everywhere -- first to set it, and then to reference it. Instead of creating a variable that's local to one function, you're creating an instance attribute. That link should help explain what's going on.

Comment: I added self. in front of all editThisLine,it now edits the other tab instead of the tab the button was clicked. I'll read more of the article once I get more time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you are missing is [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). A closure wraps up a scope with a function, so that code in the function can access variables within that associated scope. The simplest way to utilise closures when connecting signals is with a `lambda` (although some people prefer to use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)).

In your example, this would mean connecting the signal like this:

```
    aButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.runThisWhenButtonClicked(editThisLine))
    ...

def runThisWhenButtonClicked(self, editThisLine):
    print(editThisLine.text())
```

However, I think this may be "papering over the cracks" in your code, and is possibly not the best solution. A better solution would be to make proper use of the namespaces that classes provide. The `addTheTab` and `runThisWhenButtonClicked` should be refactored into a `Tab` class which has all its child widgets as attributes:

```
class Tab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tab, self).__init__(parent)
        self.editThisLine = QLineEdit()
        self.aButton = QPushButton("Stuff")
        self.aButton.clicked.connect(self.runThisWhenButtonClicked)
        ...

    def runThisWhenButtonClicked(self):
        print(self.editThisLine.text())
```

This would completely eliminate the need for closures in your example.